# How to flatten out nested array of strings in json column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

| id | contents |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | { blocks: [{ text: "abc" }, { text: "123" }] } |
| foo | { blocks: [{ text: "bar" }, { text: "moretext" }, { text: "ok" }] } |

I want to write a view of the above that looks like:

| id | contents | raw_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | {blocks: [{text: "abc"}, {text: "123"}]} | abc, 123 |
| foo | {blocks: [{text: "bar"}, {text: "moretext"}, { text: "ok"}]} | bar, moretext, ok |

This was the query I tried running:

```
select post.id, array_to_string(array_agg(jsonb_array_elements(post.contents -> 'blocks') ->> 'text')) as paragraphs from post group by id
```

But it results in the error

`aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls.`

Comment: It would be more helpful if your sample data was valid JSON

Comment: I  put quotes around values to make it valid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a JSON array of all the values is also acceptable, you can use a JSON path query:

```
select id, contents, 
       jsonb_path_query_array(contents, '$.blocks[*].text')
from post;
```

As there is no simply cast from a JSON array to a native Postgres array, and you do need that as a CSV string, you need to unnest and aggregate with a scalar sub-query:

```
select id, contents, 
       (select string_agg(x.item ->> 'text', ', ')
        from jsonb_array_elements(contents -> 'blocks') as x(item)) as raw_text
from post;
```

The reason for your error is, that you are mixing nesting multiple aggregate and set returning function which simply isn't supported.